# What will I not be able to do in Ubuntu that I can do in window 7?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I am using win7, with virtualbox to test Ubuntu. I am planning move to Linux system,but not 100% sure.

What I can do in win7 that I cannot do in Ubuntu? I need the answer to make my decision.

Comment: I give you an example, you can not run sandisk dashboard in linux.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find out is make a switch  as a dual boot, refrain from using your windows until really necessary unavoidable, and look for solutions of your every day programs.

This is how I did it and not touched Windows in about 10 month and not regretting it.

This is really the only way for you to know if you will miss any of the Windows available programs you use or if you're unable to find Linux substitutes for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are things on both sides, Ubuntu doesn't comes with preinstalled media plugins, but comes with all-in-one terminal, with compiling options. While Windows comes with X-Box for gaming purposes. Ubuntu doesn't comes for gaming, it is for work or learning. which doesn't seems true for Windows, when new.

Answer (score 0):

- Ubuntu cannot run Windows viruses
- Linux does not easily get recruited into botnets.
- The source code for everything in the GNU/Linux world is freely available for your inspection.
- You can fix it yourself, hire an expert to fix it, report a bug (and follow its progress), or request free support on sites like AskUbuntu.
- Changes to GNU/Linux come with "changelogs", explaining what was changed, and why.
- Linux's system interface (that it shows to programs) is fully documented, and has no special tricks.
- All programs (within the Linux permission system) are equal.
- Linux doesn't hide filenames from you (like `secrets.pdf.exe`, or `$secret$`).
- See, for example [this analysis of a Single Microsoft Patch Tuesday](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/December+2016+Patch+Tuesday+Brief+and+Updates/21815)

What do you "do in Win 7"? That's the first step in your journey to GNU/Linux.

Comment: _“Ubuntu cannot run Windows viruses”_ What about Wine? _“All programs (within the Linux permission system) are equal.”_ All programs are equal in what way?